# Is there a free cross-platform tool for pure digital gate-level schematic design and simulation?

Tags: software, schematics, digital-logic, vhdl, hdl

I'm searching a software tool for teaching purpose in order to teach students digital hardware (starting from logic gates level).

Do you have something in mind that will allow making simple graphical schematics and simulate them?

In best case it should be free (or at least with time-unlimited demo) and run on Windows, Linux and Mac OS.

If it could simulate VHDL or any other HDL it would be a plus.

Answer (score 4):

[tkgate](http://www.tkgate.org/). Purely digital event driven gate-level circuit simulation and presumably schematic capture. Should work on many operating systems, including Windows, Mac OS X, Linux and FreeBSD. Also, it's open source.

Comment: http://www.tkgate.org/

Answer (score 1):

[GNU Electric](http://www.gnu.org/s/electric/) is *incredible overkill*, but it will do what you want.